# How can a winforms application accept user input without having focus?

Tags: c#, winforms, focus, user-input

I am using a project hosted at http://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/ It uses default Microsoft keyboard input codes to SendKeys what key is actually pressed.

If I have to use my winform as keyboard to perform keyboard functionality like Microsoft's tool, On-Screen Keyboard, I have to provide focus to the application that needs to be edited.

Let's say for example I have to type a document in Word, so it has focus. But when I click my form buttons, focus transfers to my Form and nothing gets written on Word.

So...

What I want is to make a form control that does not take focus but performs functionally.

Comment: You might like to finish asking your question.

Comment: Questions are meant to be asked. ;)

Comment: I think what Matt Ball means is that you haven't actually asked a question.  What have you tried, what isn't working.  Can you describe it a little bit more for those of us less familiar with the two technologies you're describing.  "as microsoft keyboard does" - you're assuming we understand how microsoft keyboard works.   Explain the problem in greater detail, outline the approach you've taken to solve it, and ask specific questions about specific problems that you preventing you from succeeding.

Comment: The question, if I am to infer correctly, is: "How do I make a winforms application accept user input without having focus?" However, that question is quite broad by itself, and as other comments have said, you need to provide more detail and example code. This could be a great question with some more info.

Comment: @Afnan: Hope you don't mind some editing to help make things more clear. I'm also going to change the title and tags to hopefully interest more people who may be able to help.

Comment: Yes i understood that if i am not going to help other understand my question how can they help me.Thank you all

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The WS_EX_NOACTIVATE window style flag was designed to do this.  Here's a sample form that implements it:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form {
    public Form1() {
        InitializeComponent();
        this.TopMost = true;
    }
    protected override CreateParams CreateParams {
        get {
            var cp = base.CreateParams;
            cp.ExStyle |= 0x08000000; // Turn on WS_EX_NOACTIVATE;
            return cp;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Keyboard Spy: implementation and counter measures](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/system/KeyLogger.aspx)